# My first java example returns error - Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol,

Tags: java

[Training picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlxzL.jpg) - I attached my picture that I am learning from, as you can see, he runs/compiles the code and the output was correct. But when I try to run similar example, I get error.

My first java example file compiles fine, but throws error at runtime. I used plain text editor to create the file. It is in soccer folder/package and in Game.java file. Please help to fix the error.

```
package soccer;

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Goals = 10;
        Player firstPlayer = new Player();

    }

}


run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Player
  location: class soccer.Game
    at soccer.Game.main(Game.java:11)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Try compiling it via the command line with `javac` and see the compiler errors.

Comment: Did you create the class `Player`?  If it's in a different package then you need to import it

Comment: I tried compiling it with command line too. No error at compilation. Only runtime error.

Comment: No, I don't have Player class. Do I need one? I am going through a Java SE8 class online and they didn't mention anything about creating a class before compiling this .java file. The tutor gets correct answer.

Comment: And why did I get -2 for this question? is it not a valid question?

Comment: I did not vote, but you got -2 because you didn't try to `understand` the error. It clearly says that *it does not know what is player*. So you need to define a player class first and import it for code to compile.

Comment: Please review the attachment where my tutor compiles a similar example without any error.

Comment: Have a look at your tutor's example. I want you to notice the two tabs at top which show opened files. One file is **Item.java** and your tutor is using that file into his code. All is good and java knows what `Item` is. But in your code, you probably dont have any file called **Player.java** that defines the class `Player`. Hence java doesn't know what it is. 

Please dont try to create objects randomly. This is programming. You must define *each and every* thing for computer. Currently computer has no idea what is `Player`. Define it for your computer or tell it where is it defined!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a class called `Player`. In the "training picture", it shows another file called "Item.java". That actually contains a class called `Item`. In the "ShoppingCart.java" file, we can write

```
Item item = new Item()
```

because the class `Item` is defined in `Item.java`.

Did you write a `Player` class in a file called "Player.java"? Probably not. **Remember, you can only refer to something if it is defined.**

The error says that symbol `Player` cannot be found, probably because it is not defined. If it is not defined, where do you think the computer would find such a class called `Player` for you?

---

There is another possibility. You might say, I defined class `Player` in "Player.java" but it still cannot find the symbol! Now you should check the contents of "Player.java". Look at the package. Is it the same as that of `Game`? If it is not, change it to the same as `Game`, i.e. `soccer`. Or you can import that using an import statement.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Class called Player then compile, because

```
Player firstplayer=new Player();
```

Object creation, this is an object to object linking, which happens only at runtime, so you are getting runtime exception.
Simply create a Player class and put a

```
System.out.println("like this");
```

Your code will run perfectly.

Comment: Why do you use a code block to put all the text in?